# Community Moderator closing duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, community-user

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29269879/are-asynchrous-callbacks-threadsafe) was closed as a duplicate by yours truly and [Community Moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community), which is described as a *background process*.

I know how **I** determined that it was a duplicate: I searched for certain key words and then read a few posts looking for a good match.

What about Community Moderator?  Was it really an automatic process or human intervention under this name?

Comment: And now you can do so too...

Comment: @Deduplicator - Yes. Kinda funny.